# What is the best way to make a configurable text elements for HTML5 App

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am doing a HTML5 app. Everything works well. The client suddenly requested that he needs to change error messages and text labels as he wish after completing the code, but without touching the HTML5. So I got two solutions in to my mind.

1 Use javascript variables

```
// Error Messages

    var msg_authentication_failed = "The username or password is invalid. Please try again";
```

and use this variable as I wanted.

2  Use XML file (Or JSON)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
     <ErrorMessages>
           <AuthenticationFail>The username or password is invalid. Please try again</AuthenticationFail>
     </ErrorMessages>
```

Load XML file and set values using it's tag names.

However I feel that the 2nd solution is easy to maintain by the client but performance wise it's not good.

Is there any other possible way to get done this kind of requirement? Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running a jQuery Mobile project which supports around 6 languages (from Europe) and what I did was simply maintaining the labels in a JSON string.

using the event `pagebeforeshow` I update the labels when showing form element's labels. If it is an error message, I wrote a custom function that can access the string based on the labelID.

More than XML, JSON is extremely easy to handle. I would suggest you to go ahead with it.

Comment: Thanks Mayu for your reply. What I am worrying with JSON is it's really friendly for developers, but for average user. It's quite hard.

Comment: If you have a well formatted `JSON` string then it would be easy for any user who can understand `XML`. Its just my thought :)